# Modify keys in nested dictionary to match for post

Tags: python, api, dictionary, nested

So I run a GET to system A and get this output:

```
'{
  "comment": "A good object",
  "number": "1.1",
  "extra_stuff": {
        "extra_id": {"value": 100},
        "extra_name": {"value": "Test"},
        }
 }'
```

Before I POST to system B, I need to translate (and omit) certain keys (but keep the value). What I want from this GET and translate is ONLY the nested dictionary keys (keys in extra_stuff) and only one of them.

Translation:

```
mapping_dict = { 'extra_id': 'id' }
dict_to_post = { '#KEY extra_ID': #VALUE FROM extra_ID# :, 'name' : Test, 'other' : True }
```

I got a function for translating the dictionary keys from another question put here:

```
def update_dict_keys(obj, mapping_dict):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {mapping_dict[k]: update_dict_keys(v, mapping_dict) for k, v in obj.iteritems()}
    else:

        return obj
```

But I am unsure how to send only the nested dictionary into that function, I only seem to put the "main" dictionary in there. Not sure what the best way about it is. I would further need to handle information from the "main" dictionary as well in another post.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, there is a `,` behind `{"value": "Test"}` bacause this is no valid `json` and your get response looks like `json`.

If this is only a mistake in your post here, you could
use `json.loads()` to get a dictionary from your response string:

```
import json

res = '{
    "comment": "A good object",
    "number": "1.1",
    "extra_stuff": {
            "extra_id": {"value": 100},
            "extra_name": {"value": "Test"}
    }
}'

# convert to dict
res_dict = json.loads(res)

# do your mapping
dict_to_post = { 'extra_id': res_dict['extra_stuff']['extra_id']['value']}

# dict_to_post is {'extra_id': 100} now
```

Furthermore I don't understand what you need the `mapping_dict` for. Do you want to have {'id': 100} as result?

Comment: Sorry, typo! Was cleaning up the code to make the example simpler. The mapping is for changing the key name of the GET dictionary (the nested dictionary with the key "extra_id") so it can match the necessary key name for the POST later.

Comment: I have some errors when I try to convert it:
    res_dict = json.loads(res)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

Comment: If it is just this one key as you said in your question it's enough to do `dict_to_post = { 'id': res_dict['extra_stuff']['extra_id']['value']}` You don't need your matching dict then. If you want to match more keys, tell me and I gonna update my answer. For your stacktrace: it does not tell me you're exception.

Comment: I dont have much experience with this (if that is not obvious :), this is how the json results look like before I try to convert it (pprint) :
[{u'comment': u'A good object',
  u'extra_stuff': {u'extra_id': {u'value': u'100'},
                u'extra_name': {u'value': 'Test'}},
  u'number': u'1.1'}]

Comment: I want the mapping to be adjustable so I can adjust the key names in the mapping dict to fit into different scenarios, so yes it will be more than just this specific example.

Sorry, missed the traceback:
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that the response I get is already decoded! Problem I had was that the decoded response was a list with a dictionary within a dictionary.